# Why when I use two functions in a program only one works

Tags: python, function, if-statement

Im doing a simple code jam for school and my question is why when I use two functions in a program only one works or it doesn't work at all. one_player_# is the name of my function. I want to use if- statement to call the functions for the user to choose a game-mode. My game modes is one player and two player. So I  made the code for the game a function so I can make it possible for the user to choose a game mode through the if -statement but when you choose a game-mode it doesn't work. Is what im trying to do not possible? Hope that makes sense plz explain what i'm dong wrong thanks.

```
# choose your game mode
op = input("Choose gamemode - Two player = 2  One player = 1 : ")
if op == 2 :
    print (two_player_op())
if op == 1:
    print(one_player_op())

#One player Function
def one_player_op():
       # I put game code for 1st play here


#Two player function
def two_player_op():
          # I put game code for two player here
#code ends
```

I expect for it to allow the user to choose a game-mode and run it rather than giving me a blank response

Comment: `op = int(input(..))`

Comment: Also, the methods should be defined before they are used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is reading from top to bottom.
First define the functions, and then call them. Also, use "int" before input.

```
#One player Function
def one_player_op():
       # I put game code for 1st play here


#Two player function
def two_player_op():
          # I put game code for two player here
#code endsenter code here
    # choose your game mode

op = int(input("Choose gamemode - Two player = 2  One player = 1 : "))

if op == 2:
    print (two_player_op())
if op == 1:
    print(one_player_op())
```

Comment: You might want to use elif/else to make mutually exclusive options and indicate invalid choices

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you are comparing an int to another int if you want to get a True result. Keep in mind the types of data you are manipulating. Also in python, you must define functions before code that runs them. Not code that defines them, but the code that is actually executing the function.
So in your case:

```
#One player Function
def one_player_op():
       # I put game code for 1st play here

#Two player function
def two_player_op():
          # I put game code for two player here

# choose your game mode
op = int(input("Choose gamemode - Two player = 2  One player = 1 : "))
if op == 2 :
    print (two_player_op())
if op == 1:
    print(one_player_op())
#code ends
```

Incorporating the comment, if you want to make it clear that only one game mode is to run, for code readability purposes, and to make sure any future additional conditional options you might add do what you intend them to do you can write the conditionals as:

```
if op == 2 :
    print (two_player_op())
elif op == 1:
    print(one_player_op())
#code ends
```

Comment: Might want to use elif/else to make mutually exclusive options and indicate invalid choices

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle other options added by user and not only (1 or 2)

```
# choose your game mode
op = input("Choose gamemode - Two player = 2  One player = 1 : ")
try:
    user_input = int(op)
except ValueError:
    # handles characters added in input e.g "one", "play"
    print("Please enter values between 1 or 2 only ")

if user_input == 2 :
    print (two_player_op())
elif user_input== 1:
    print(one_player_op())
else:
    print("Please enter values between 1 or 2 only ")

#One player Function
def one_player_op():
       # I put game code for 1st play here

#Two player function
def two_player_op():
          # I put game code for two player here
#code ends
```

Comment: You don't need to print the same message twice in case of parsing error

Answer (score -1):

Need to convert `input` string to int.

> op = int(input("........'))

Comment: That by itself would not suffice